# Do you have tips for a long-time noob to ask better questions and reduce drama?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479691/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-number-of-records-queried) was the result of a previous disaster that I actually deleted.

I don't think I'm stupid. But it becomes more and more obvious that I think differently than most programmers or SO participants.  To be clear, I have worked as a programmer, but I am not a programmer.  I do some coding.  Regardless, I would genuinely appreciate some critique on my question-asking skills.  It seems that more often than not my questions are met with certain disdain or misunderstanding.  Is my world honestly so different?

Comment: You shouldn't be deleting posts just to re-ask them.  Edit the question if you've come up with ways to improve it.

Comment: In general I completely agree.  But the post had already been downvoted and the conversation had been directed to the example I gave.  Rewording it, especially removing the example, essentially changed the entire question.

Comment: I can't see anything *major* wrong with your question (you got a [useful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29480082/4200092) to it, at least), so I can only agree with what @Servy said.

Comment: It's the same problem, with the same fundamental question, so no.  Deleting and re-asking a question just to reset it's score to zero is highly inappropriate behavior.

Comment: I ended up getting lots of useful answers!  But the comments and votecount lead me to believe there *is* something wrong with it or the way I asked it.

Comment: @Servy I guess I see that point.

Comment: The title gets you off to a bad start: `Is it possible to ...` implies a Yes or No answer.  The body of it doesnt improve on it.

Comment: Great tip.  So "How do you" may have been better?

Comment: Definitely.  Yes/No questions are worse than useless.  HOW is this accomplished is the goal here.  And don't forget--what have you tried?  Why didn't it work?  Is there a fix, or is there a better way to meet your goals?  Yes?  No.

Comment: Personally I'm a firm believer in "to get code, you should give code", for a couple of reasons. First it shows you at least made an attempt. Asking for code without at least showing you did something comes across as though you're asking someone else to do your work for you for free instead of helping you out from what you already did. As @Plutonix said `Is it possible` implies a yes or no answer, especially since you didn't expand in the body. I would've expanded with "I've got code that does XYZ and I need it to do ABC. What's missing?"

Comment: I was actually in the process of answering that post @ScottBeeson, when you suddenly deleted it. I understand that the sudden downvotes got to you, but it would probably have balanced out if you had given it a while to rest. Anyway, you reposted it, and got the answer in the end. A thought: you seem very quick to defend, or take a defensive stance anyway. I think this will only strengthen a negative trend (in a post like yours for example). Let someone else defend your post ;-)

Comment: @Mackan: I think you hit on something critical to my persona.  I was the administrator  of an online game for years and I think I've conditioned myself to negative interactions on the internet so much that I jump the gun.  Thanks for pointing this out, I will try to be more patient.  It's amplified by the fact that I've hit a road block and I'm waiting on people on the internet and often get hit with more questions instead of answers!  :)

Comment: @ScottBeeson I typically apply a 72-hour rule to myself.  When I hit a road-block, I must spend at least three days working on the problem before it's even remotely acceptable to post to the Stack Exchange.  This gives you 72 hours to: 1) collect more details, 2) try more things that end up being offered as examples of what doesn't work, 3) see that it can be broken down into smaller problems (which makes the question you have to ask simpler and more specific which is good), or 4) best case scenario, just solve it on your own using existing [so] answers and not have to post your own question.

Comment: That's admirable.  I might start with a 24 hour rule.  I usually get impatient if I don't have an answer within an hour, so that would be a drastic change.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Concrete examples are perhaps the single most helpful tool you can use when asking a question. Your question didn't have any examples, which impedes other users' ability to understand what you're asking. (Not to say that *every* question *must* have an example of some kind, but rare is the question that isn't helped by an example.)

The usefulness of examples is clear from the comment thread below your question. The apparently-incorrect solution `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table` prompted some great clarifying discussion. In order to make your question better, you could incorporate that example directly into your question and explain why it isn't sufficient. A concrete example of what you *don't* want can go a long way in helping other users understand what you *do* want. Show the best that you have, and explain how that's different from what you want.

As others have said, you shouldn't delete and re-ask questions. I know it can be very difficult to recover when your question has become (in your words) "a garbage dump of misunderstanding." Here's some concrete advice on what to do when that happens:

- When you notice that users don't understand your question, check to see if there's anything more you can add to it. Short examples are great; long examples are better than nothing. (*Very* long examples signal to readers that you have no clue what you're asking. Avoid page-long examples.)
- If confusion and downvotes persist, you may need to delete the answer temporarily to edit it. Carefully review each comment and see why the commenter misunderstood your question. Think about what you can do to avoid that confusion.
- Once you are confident you have removed a source of confusion with your edits, you may wish to clean up the comments section. As a reader, long comment chains (especially on downvoted questions) scare me away very quickly: it signals to me that critical information is still hidden deep in the comments thread, instead of being in the question.

  - If a comment asks for clarification about something, and you have clarified that thing in your question, then the comment is by definition *obsolete* and you may correctly flag it for removal. (Note, however, that if you didn't do a good job with your clarification, this may bite you later, when someone else posts another comment with the same confusion.)

To summarize:

- Don't be afraid to use examples. You've thought long and hard about the problem, and you need to communicate all that long-and-hard thinking quickly to someone who reads your question. Examples are great for that.
- Use question-editing to move clarification from the comment thread into your question.
- Use flags to keep the comments thread clean. Once you've moved clarification into the question, the comment has served its purpose should be removed.
- You may delete your question temporarily to review comments and clean it up, especially if you have many comments that ask for complex clarifying changes.